# Sequelize: Defining Associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Reading the documentation of `Sequelize` I'm in some level confused, what `Sequelize` will provide automatically for us and what we need to explicitly tell it.
I have two models: `User` and `Post`. As you have guessed a User can *have* multiple Posts and a Post *belongs* only to one User. Setting the respective relationships will look so:

```
Post.associate = (models) => {
  Post.belongsTo(models.users, {
    as:'user',
    foreignKey: {
      name: 'user_id',
      allowNull: false
    }
  }
}

User.associate = (models) => {
  User.hasMany(models.posts, {
    as:'posts',
    onDelete:'CASCADE',
    onUpdate:'CASCADE' 
  }
}
```

My question is: should I specify the `foreignKey` one more time when declaring the `hasMany` association, or it is enough for Sequelize to have the `foreignKey` in one of the declared relationships between two models (in the example - `belongsTo`)?

Answer (score 0):

From what I think happens:

- Sequelize goes through all your association one by one
- If you already provided a foreign key name then fine
- Else it will guess/name the foreign key on its own

Like what it says about `options.foreignKey` in docs e.g. for belongsTo : [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-belongsTo](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-belongsTo) (same description for hasOne, hasMany, belongsToMany )

> options.foreignKey ||  string  OR  object  ||  optional

> The name of the foreign key attribute in the source table or an object representing the type definition for the foreign column (see Sequelize.define for syntax). When using an object, you can add a name property to set the name of the column. **Defaults to the name of target + primary key of target**

If sequelize is guessing your foreignKey names then you will face issues only if your foreignKey name is not matching (tableName + Id) OR (tableName + _ + id)

Hence, better to give foreignKey names on your own to both sides of associations to never face any issues going further.